# how to resize the option in select tag of html

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm doing my webpage responsive using Media query. In normal system screen width, it works normal, but when I re-sized to mobile view it looks like the following image.

[image]

*(When the web page is viewed in mobile (device mode) view ex: amazon kindle, Apple iPad, Apple iPad Mini, Apple iPhone 6+, Blackberry Phonebook, Google Nexus 7 / 10)*

Contents of `<option></option>` tag is going out of screen. I tried to reduce the width, but it just reduce the width of select tag but not its option size

But in some other device view ex: Apple iPhone 4 / 5 / 6, Google Nexus 4, LGOptimus L70 and Samsung S3, etc it looks fine like the following image

[image]

How shall I resize that dropdown option?

Comment: Select tag by default takes the width of the options. Can you share the code for the options ? Or try giving a percentage value as width in style for the select tag.

Comment: You should add a code snippet.